# Does DotNetOpenAuth require maintenance updates?

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, dotnetopenauth

I noticed a web site recently that is using a [DotNetOpenAuth](http://dotnetopenauth.net/) DLL compiled in May 2011 for OpenId authentication. Everything works just fine but I was wondering if this is safe and secure.

Is the DotNetOpenAuth library a 'set it and forget it' type library or one that needs constant maintenance updates?